# Xen and Windows 7 domU, can't find CD/DVD drivers

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, xen

Simple question. When installing Windows 7 under Xen as domU with Fedora 20 dom0, it stops before installing asking for the CD/DVD drivers. I just can't get it past this point. KVM does it too through qemu unless I specify ide for everything.

Is there a solution for xen? Here's my config:

```
builder = "hvm"
name = "win7"
memory = "4096"
vcpus = 4
disk = [ 'tap:qcow2:/data/vms/w7.qcow2,hda,w','file:/home/aiden/Desktop/w7.iso,hdc:cdrom,r']
boot="dc"
sdl=1
xen_platform_pci=1
pci=['01:00.0']
```

Been going around in circles trying to get Windows 7 to install all day. Any help appriciated.

Comment: Have you checked your .iso? (md5 hash?)  Sounds more like you have a bad iso.

Comment: Yes turns out the iso was truncated by ... a few bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... I guess I should put this as an answer...

Verify your .iso file is valid.  Truncated or corrupted .iso files can cause issues when attempting to mount them in the guest OS.